# Logistic regression: Drop Insignificant prediction Variables

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I am using R to perform logistic regression on my data set. My data set has more than 50 variables.

The challenge is to write code in R that can assess the statistical validity of certain records and variables (e.g., p values >.05)  and eliminate records and variables from the model based on parameters such as that.

Is there any already implemented method to do this? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: take a look at stats::step or MASS::stepAIC. This is of course based on AIC and not p-values, but this is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @J.R. except that it's not (more appropriate). Doing feature selection like this is the same as doing it via p values, you are just using a different alpha (significance) level when you do so via AIC.

Comment: Agree with Gavin. The penalties using AIC are fairly modest especially when used in a stepwise fashion.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, point taken and thanks. With the "probably..." argument, I simply had convenience when deciding between non-nested models in mind. OP can consult Cross Validated for a discussion or other relevant approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the implementation of a basic function that will take a set of predictor variables and eliminate those variables step-by-step until a linear model is found that only has predictors below the desired significance level.

```
reverse.step <- function(y, b, df, alpha=0.05) {
  # y = dependent variable name (as character) e.g. 'Height', 
  # b = vector of explanatory variable names (as characters) e.g. 
  # c('x1','x2','x3',...), # df = data frame
  sum <- summary(lm(paste(paste(y,' ~ ', sep=''), 
                          paste(b, collapse='+'), sep=''), data=df))
  cat(b)
  cat("\n")
  pvals <- sum$coeff[2:nrow(sum$coeff),4]
  if (pvals[which.max(pvals)] < alpha) {
    return(sum)
  }
  new.b <- names(pvals[-which.max(pvals)])
  if (length(new.b) == 0 | length(new.b) == length(b)) {
    return(sum)
  } else {
    return(reverse.step(y, new.b, df, alpha))
  }
}
```

It may not be the most robust function, but it will get you started.

You could also check out the regsubsets method in the library [leaps](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html).